# regular expression in main title with `bquote`?

Tags: r, plot, expression

I have myplot function that uses arg, which is part of the plot title. I want arg to be either of class character or expression. However, I can't get it work when arg is of class expression. Example:

```
myplot <- function(..., arg){
  plot(..., main = bquote(paste("TPR(", .(arg), ")")))
}

# it works for characters
myplot(1, arg="t")

# but it won't work for expressions (I would like to have Greek letters with a "hat" in the title)

myplot(1, arg=expression(hat(alpha[1])))

# however, using directly the expression works:
plot(1, main=bquote(paste("TPR(", hat(alpha[1]), ")")))
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regular expressions? Are you confusing those with R expressions? Because they are very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
f <- function(lab, tpr=1) {
    if(is.expression(lab)) {
        lab <- lab[[1]]
    }
    plot(1,1,main=bquote(plain(TPR) * (.(lab)) == .(tpr)))
}

f("hatalpha")
f(expression(hat(alpha)))
```

An "expression" is really a vector of objects. Here we explicitly extract the first element (in this case a "call") and insert it into the expression for the title of the plot. I've also re-written the expression to avoid `paste()` which often isn't necessary.